# Вывод информации на статическую страницу Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, плагин, wp-plugin

Пишу плагин для вывода информации из базы данных.
Есть функция:

```
function show_list_oil_filters($content) {
global $wpdb;

$excel_out = $wpdb->prefix.excel_out;

$results = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT DISTINCT `Brand` FROM $excel_out");


foreach ($results as $marca) {
    echo do_shortcode("[filteroption val='".$marca->Brand."']");
}

return $content;}
```

Эта функция производит выборку и выводит результат шорткодом на статическую страницу.

Код шорткода:

```
function filteroption_func_handler_oil_filters($att) {

/*Для примера*/
return "<option value='" . $att['val'] . "'> Received attribute: " . $att['val'] . "</option>";}
```

Информация выводится на статическую станицу, но не в том месте, где нужно.

Как вывести полученную информацию в нужном месте, в теге `<select></select>` на статической странице?

Answer (score 1):

Где вы выводите шоткод, там и происходит замена.
Полагаю что функция `show_list_oil_filters` отрабатывает по фильтру  `the_content`. Если так, то ее код может быть следующим:

```
function show_list_oil_filters($content) {
    global $wpdb;

    $excel_out = $wpdb->prefix.excel_out;

    $results = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT DISTINCT `Brand` FROM $excel_out");

    echo '<select>';
    foreach ($results as $marca) {
        echo do_shortcode("[filteroption val='".$marca->Brand."']");
    }
    echo '</select>';

    return $content;
}
```

Для более развернутого ответа и решения необходимо больше информации.